# How to lock a hosted WorkflowDesigner from editing?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, rehosting

Is it possible to add a locked WorkflowDesigner View to a WPF application? By locked I mean no change or editing whatsoever can be done to the Workflow Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by changing the ReadOnlyState

```
var readOnlyState = _workflowDesigner.Context.Items.GetValue<ReadOnlyState>();
readOnlyState.IsReadOnly = true;
```